# preg_match - to allow only one dash

Tags: php, preg-match

I'm using preg_match and its working to allow; numbers, letters and dash. but i want to limit the dash to 1 only. i tried added {1} before and after the dash but its still allowing more than one. what am i doing wrong?

```
if (!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9-]+$/", $username)) {
                $nameErr = "The username you selected was invalid.<br>Valid characters are dashes (one only), letters and numbers.";
            } else {
```

This is the code that i'm using.

Thanks

Comment: try this and tell me it worked or not. !preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9\-]+$/", $username)

Comment: If you do not need to check if `-` comes at the start, end or multiple conseuctive `-`, use JustOnUnderMillions solution. Else, use `"/^[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:-[A-Za-z0-9]+)?$/D"`

Comment: @Mubashar Iqbal that allowed 2 --

Comment: Is the dash required or optional? A positive lookahead could confirm that you have only 1 `-`. `^(?=^[^-]+-[^-]+$)[A-Za-z0-9-]+$`.

Answer (score 1):

Make an extra test for the dash count to keep it simple.

```
if (!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9\-]+$/", $username) || substr_count($username,'-') > 1) {
  $nameErr = "The username you selected was invalid.<br>Valid characters are dashes (one only), letters and numbers.";
}
```

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Then make an answer and dont spam comments ;-)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew An answer should allways have a little explanation. Here it is just the note:_make an extra test_  but if i add your regex i have to exlpain a little why this works, currently i cant or lets they can not fully explain the regex ;-)

Comment: Ok, I posted mine.

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to validate a string that can contain one or zero hyphens in an alphanumeric string, you may use a negative lookahead in your pattern to fail the match if 2 hyphens are found:

```
"/^(?![^-]*-[^-]*-)[A-Za-z0-9-]+$/D"
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

*Pattern details*:

- `^` - start of a string
- `(?![^-]*-[^-]*-)` - fail the match if there are 2 hyphens separated with 0+
  chars other than `-`
- `[A-Za-z0-9-]+` - 1 or more alphanumeric chars or hyphens
- `$` - the  very end of the string (since `/D` modifier is used).

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kocMjM/1) (pattern modified to account for a multiline string input).

Note that if you want to disallow `-` to appear at the start/end of the string, and several consecutive `-`s, use a more straight-forward pattern:

```
"/^[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:-[A-Za-z0-9]+)?$/D"
```

where `^[A-Za-z0-9]+` will match 1+ alphanumeric chars at the start of the stirng, and `(?:-[A-Za-z0-9]+)?$` will match 1 or 0 occurrences of a `-` followed with 1+ alphanumeric chars at the end of the string.

Comment: @Liam That answer should be checked as right. He fixes your regex ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $username = "abc-edf-tru-ksk-5-ll-hr-foam-6-inch-queen-anroid-phone-stackoverflow-72-x-70-x-6290321_1";
```

> This below code allow hypens(-) and underscore(_)

```
if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+(-[a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)*$/', $username))
{
            echo "The username you selected valid characters are hypens,underscores, letters and numbers.";
}
```

> allow only hypen(-)

```
if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+(-[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)*$/'), $username))
{
            echo "The username you selected valid characters are hypens(only), letters and numbers.";
}
```

> allow only underscore(_)

```
if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9\_]+(-[a-zA-Z0-9\_]+)*$/'), $username))
{
            echo "The username you selected valid characters are underscores(only),underscores, letters and numbers.";
}
```

> not allow hypens, underscores and symbols

```
if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$/'), $username))
{
            echo "The username you selected valid characters are letters and numbers.";
}
```